# Known Conformal Field Theories?

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory

What is a comprehensive list of all known Conformal Field Theories e.g. in 2 dimensions? CFT references usually talk about just minimal models and maybe Wess-Zumino-Witten model. I'm curious to learn about various other exotic CFTs that have been studied.

Comment: The question might be broad, but I think it's an interesting one.

Comment: @M.Jo Yes, I am indeed interested in an answer to this broad question, and I am rather surprised that it seems to be out of scope here on stack exchange. Please, feel free to post hints on which literature to look up for various CFTs here in the comments, if you know of some.

Comment: @M.Jo Also, If you would like to see this question reopened, please consider clicking the "reopen" vote button under the question.

Comment: The thing about Stackexchange is that it's a Q&A site that tries to provide good quality answers to the questions.  Physics generally is focused on conceptual physics questions.  Listing off all theories from a concept is not a conceptual question on it's own, which is generally why they are closed.

Comment: @Kagaratsch I don't have sufficient privileges to vote for reopening the question, sorry...

Comment: @JMac "Listing off all theories from a concept is not a conceptual question on it's own." This comment doesn't make any sense to me. 
Just to be clear, there are people whose research consists precisely in classifying interesting theories. Example:  the classification of all supersymmetric algebras by Nahm, or more recently
this classification (https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01217)
of deformations of superconformal theories.
What you might argue is that this is closer to math than physics, but that's another debate...

Comment: @M.Jo The conceptual work in that is determining what would be suitable for the list.  The actual question of what the list contains isn't really conceptual if you ask me.  "Provide me a list of everything where this concept applies" is different than "How can I determine what falls under this conceptual framework?"  One is able to just provide a list without any explanation, the other actually addresses concepts.

Comment: @JMac I added the "Resource Recommendations" tag to make the question more appropriate to the point of view you point out.

Comment: Do you only want the ones relevant to physics or some other constraint. Because otherwise cranking up the rank on W algebras or making ever more complicated cosets. Some criteria to use to make the list finite and small.

Comment: @AHusain The cases relevant to physics is my primary interest, but if there is a systematic way to generate more examples than it would be good if this way to generate theories was also mentioned.